# Create nested list based on CSS classes using JavaScript / jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What's the best way to create an unordered list given the following HTML where **Clothing** is a parent of its children: **Hoodies**, **T-shirts**. And **T-shirts** is a parent of **Sweaters**. **Sweaters** is a parent of **testing**, etc.

Ideally working with the CSS classes is great, but if there's a way with the `&nbsp;` that's fine as well.

I've tried looping through but couldn't find a way using the `for` loop in JavaScript yet.

```html
<select name="parent" id="parent" class="postform">
    <option value="-1">None</option>
    <option class="level-0" value="2081">Clothing</option>
    <option class="level-1" value="2082">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Hoodies</option>
    <option class="level-1" value="2083">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;T-shirts</option>
    <option class="level-2" value="2084">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Sweaters</option>
    <option class="level-3" value="2085">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;testing</option>
    <option class="level-0" value="2077">Music</option>
    <option class="level-1" value="2079">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Albums</option>
    <option class="level-1" value="2078">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Singles</option>
    <option class="level-0" value="2080">Posters</option>
    <option class="level-1" value="2086">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;testing2</option>
</select>
```

So that the outputted code becomes:

```html
<ul>
    <li data-value="2081">Clothing
        <ul>
            <li data-value="2082">Hoodies</li>
            <li data-value="2083">T-shirts
                <ul>
                    <li data-value="2084">Sweaters</li>
                    <ul>
                        <li data-value="2085">testing</li>
                    </ul>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li data-value="2077">Music
        <ul>
            <li data-value="2079">Albums</li>
            <li data-value="2078">Singles</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li data-value="2080">Posters
        <ul>
            <li data-value="2086">testing2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Try `[...document.getElementById('parent').options].forEach(op => /* code */)`

Comment: You could also do something along the lines of: `let option = document.querySelector('#parent option'); while (option.nextElementSibling) { /* add to some object and update value of option */ }`

Comment: Not sure why I'm -1 but thanks so much for the help so far I'm just stumped at the moment with this. What about turning it into an object then convert the object into an unordered list? Trying now.

Comment: Yeah, that's what you should do inside the loops that I suggested :) The tricky part is you're trying to turn a flat list into a linked object, so the order matters

Comment: Sounds cool getting there thanks mate wow asking for help is such a relief!

Comment: I'm pretty sure you'll need to index all your values into an object, then use recursion to loop through the object and generate the HTML. Kinda sucks, but I can't think of a simpler way to turn flat data into complex data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no clue if this works (we'll assume no), but hopefully it can get you going the right direction

```
// you can put this on multiple lines if you want
const getLevel = op => op ? Number(op.className.split(' ').filter(a => a.includes('level-'))[0].split('-')[0]) : -1

// our indexing object
const listObj = {}

[...document.getElementById('parent').options].forEach(op => {
  const prev = op.previousElementSibling
  const level = getLevel(op)
  const prevLevel = getLevel(prev)
  // need to compare to the previous sibling then index it by parent
  const parentVal = level > 0 && level > prevLevel ? prev.value : 'top'
  if (level > -1) {
    listObj[parentVal][op.value] = {text: op.textContent, value: op.value}
  }
})

// our recursive function
const getListHtml = op => {
  const levelObj = listObj[op.value]
  const ul = levelObj && document.createElement('ul') : null
  levelObj && Object.values(levelObj).forEach(subLevel => {
    const li = document.createElement('li')
    ul.append(li)
    subLevel.text && (li.textContent = subLevel.text)
    // the recursion to get the next level
    li.append(getListHtml(listObj[subLevel.value]))
  })
  return ul
}

// start the recursive function and get back the HTML
const listHtml = getListHtml(listObj.top)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a table and separate each option and remove the border lines. Another way is to use JS and CSS to create a slideshow.

Comment: You cannot create an unordered list from a `select` tag using CSS, so that's definitely not the best way.

Comment: You sure? Well you could wrap each select tag in <div> xD Well considering that he is trying to position elements I would think CSS would be better since he's dealing with styling.

Comment: His question doesn't ask for any guidance on positioning or styling. He's only asked about creating an unordered list from a `select` tag, which cannot be done via CSS.

Comment: Oh I see. Sorry about that.

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick responses guys it really means a lot this has been bugging me for over 12 hours now!